# Adding an overlay to images within a Flexbox List

Tags: css

I know I've seen similar questions, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to get them to work on these. It's a list of images, displayed using flexbox with javascript to swap them to a larger, main container.

What I'm trying to do is to apply an overlay on hover, but for whatever reason I can't get it to work.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" class="pj_thumb" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/aqua2.jpg" class="pj_thumb"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/aqua3.jpg" class="pj_thumb"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/aqua4.jpg" class="pj_thumb"/></a></li>
</div>
```

The CSS I've been trying..

```
.thumbnails {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbnails li {
    position: relative;
}

.thumnails li:before {  
    content: "";  
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);  
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;  
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;  
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;  
    transition: background .3s linear;  
}  

.tint:hover:before {  
    background: none;  
}
```

Codepen! http://codepen.io/DylanEspey/pen/zfnpI/?editors=110

Comment: Could you post a codepen/fiddle/demo?

Comment: http://codepen.io/DylanEspey/pen/zfnpI/?editors=110
Something like this. Maybe my brain is just shutting down from finals, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to even get a color to sit above the image. This shouldn't be that hard. I could do if it was just a div>div>img, but for ul>li>img I'm blanking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ImranBug/pen/EcjKF)**

1) You made a typo `.thumnails li:before {`  should be  `.thumbnails li:before {`

2) Assuming you want to fade away the color on hover ~ You are setting background: none on tint class which is never used in HTML? ~ in demo i have changed this to apply on li.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. xD I guess I'm just worn out and making stupid mistakes. I should probably get some sleep. But really, thank you so much. I probably would have been here all night over a stupid (relatively) mistake.

Comment: I can relative with you :) ~ get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/baosd

```
.thumnails li:before {
     ^ b
```

And `.tint` didn't exist in the HTML, I think you want `.thumbnails li`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this [flexbox text overlaying on an image](https://codepen.io/MengruZhang/pen/bvxWEw)

```
flexbox text overlaying on an image
```

- First, you need to make your flexbox
- Second, put the image (as a background image) into your flexbox child
- Third, put your text to overlay on the image